# Toshiba screen pushed in and not working

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I accidentally pushed the right corner of my Toshiba laptop screen in and now when I turn it on, the right hand side of the screen does not function. Is there a fix for this?
-Gabe

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's an old one.

Comment: You can search ebay for a replacement screen for that exact laptop model. Or a broken laptop which has the screen still working. Then, either install it yourself or take it to a repair shop and they can install the new screen for you